# Как создать eslint правило на запрет импорта определенного объекта из n пакета в файле, расположение которого не соответствует паттерну?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Предположим,  есть npm-пакет `"view-engine"`.
В случае импорта объекта `Engine`: 
`import { Engine } from "view-engine";` должна быть вызвана ошибка, если файл, в котором импортируем `Engine`, расположен по пути, который НЕ соответствует паттерну, например: `**/model/index.ts`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
/* .... */
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['!**/model/index.ts'],
    rules: {
      'no-restricted-imports': ['error', { paths: [
        {
          name: 'view-engine',
          importNames: ['Engine'],
        },
      ]}],
    },
  },
],
```

*// На всякий случай: это JS-формат конфига, не JSON :)*

Comment: Еще раз спасибо:)